# What is the main different between HOC and standard component? when should i use both of them the right way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm curious about the `Higher-Order Components` and `Standard Component`, and what should i do about it.

as per docs say about:

**Higher-Order Components:**

> A higher-order component (HOC) is an advanced technique in React for **reusing** component logic. HOCs are not part of the React API, per se. They are a pattern that emerges from React’s compositional nature.

**Standard Component:**

> Components let you split the UI into independent, **reusable** pieces, and think about each piece in isolation. This page provides an introduction to the idea of components.

I just thought both of them is a reusable code to rendering.

so what is the pros cons of `HOC` and `Standard Component`, and when should i use one of them the right way?

any suggestion are welcome

Comment: Try and think of it this way,..  A component is a self contained object, an example would be say an Edit box,  HOC on the other hand might be say be a Form, it's state often is not in isolation, it's maybe sharing it's state with all the Edit Boxes, checkbox's etc, as such it's not in isolation,  A form without any edit controls wouldn't be very useful.  So here you could maybe say a Form control is a HOC of it's Edits.  You don't just stop there either, you could say you have an Application, and then routing logic.   The application is then a HOC for the routing logic.  etc.

Comment: @Keith i don't really get it, does it mean the `HOC` is like a controller of MVC?

Comment: I would say it's the M(odel) & C(ontroller), although if using Redux, you could say that's the M(odel) and maybe even C(ontroller), and then React is the View(V).  IOW: Personally I would say only ever leave React to do the V(iew),  To make things even more confusing, React also works best if you use the FLUX approach, rather than MVC.  You then don't even have to think about HOC, because that's maintained elsewhere, or even not maintained at all, as it some cases it's implicitly done for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course!, Standard Component is a reusable piece and even HOC is also a component which is used to reuse the component logic.

A **Higher Order Component** is just a React Component that wraps another one.
 
React HOC pattern is usually implemented as a function, which is basically a classfactory that has the following signature in haskell inspired pseudocode

```
hocFactory:: W: React.Component => E: React.Component
```

> Where W (WrappedComponent) is the React.Component being wrapped
>   and E(Enhanced Component) is the new, HOC, React.Component being
>   returned.
>
> The “wraps” part of the definition is intentionally vague because it
>   can mean one of two things:
>
> - Props Proxy: The HOC manipulates the props being passed to
>     the WrappedComponent W.
> - Inheritance Inversion: The HOC extends the WrappedComponent W.

**At a high level HOC enables you to:**

- Props manipulation
- Code reuse, logic and bootstrap abstraction
- State abstraction and manipulation
- Render Highjacking

which you cannot alter when using standard component.

So basically if you need to manipulate props and interfere with rendering process you have to use HOC over standard component.

**Simple example of HOC**

```
import React from 'react';
import AuthService from '../services/AuthService';

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export default class AuthProvider extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            authService: new AuthService(),
            loggedIn: false, 
            userSigninFetching: true,
            userSigninError: '',
            user: null
        }   
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.processAuthState();
    }

    processAuthState = () => {
        this.setState({ userSigninFetching: true });

        const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))

        if (!user) {
            this.setState({
                loggedIn: false,
                userSigninFetching: false,
                userSigninError: "Login Failed",
                user: null
            });
            return;
        } 

        this.setState({
            loggedIn: true,
            userSigninFetching: false,
            userSigninError: "Successfully Logged In",
            user: user
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <AuthContext.Provider value={{ authState: this.state }}>
                {this.props.children}
            </AuthContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}


export const withAuth = (BaseComponent) => class AuthComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <AuthContext.Consumer>
                {(context) =>  (
                    <BaseComponent
                        {...this.props}
                        authState={context ? context.authState : {
                            loggedIn: false,
                            userSigninFetching: false,
                            userSigninError: "",
                            user: null
                        }}
                    />
                )}
            </AuthContext.Consumer>
        )
    }
}
```

Now let's wrap your component with **withAuth** to access auth state from the component itself.

```
import { withAuth } from '../providers/AuthProvider';

const myComponent = ({ authState }) => {
    return (
        <div>Custom component</div>
    );
}

export default withAuth(myComponent);
```

So now you can access your application auth state inside your **myComponent**.

Blockquote

[Here is the react guide for HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

[Also a good blog to dive in to depth of HOC](https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e)

Comment: could you give a simple example how to implemented `HOC`?, as commented by Keith _it's maybe sharing it's state_. i'm interesting to learn HOC from now

Comment: @flix I updated answer with an simple example of how to access auth state of you application inside a component you use with the use of HOC pattern.